# Calling Python code from TCL and checking its return value

Tags: python, tcl

I need to call Python code within a TCL script and check its exit status to determine if the Python code executed successfully or not.

TCL script:

```
if {[catch {exec "python C:\\tools\\tcl\\myexamples\\sample.py"} results] == 0 } {
    puts "No Error $results"
} else {
    puts "Error $results"
}
```

Python Code:

```
import sys

def main():
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return main()
```

However, when I execute the TCL script, I get the error below:

```
$ tclsh85.exe  ../myexamples/1.tcl
Error couldn't execute "python C:\tools\tcl\myexamples\sample.py": no such file or directory
```

But the file does exist:

```
C:\tools\tcl\myexamples>dir sample.py
Directory of C:\tools\tcl\myexamples
07-08-2019  11:23 AM               199 sample.py
1 File(s)            199 bytes
```

What is the issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: My TCL is rusty, but I think the TCL script is trying to execute "python c:\\tools\\etc" as a file path ... It seems like exec can take multiple command line arguments. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec, so you don't need the quotes.

Comment: As @aschultz says, it seems TCL thinks it's one command. Maybe close the quotes after python and open them again for the path to your python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` commands takes each argument to the script as a separate Tcl argument. That means that the simple fix is to change:

```
exec "python C:\\tools\\tcl\\myexamples\\sample.py"
```

to:

```
exec python "C:\\tools\\tcl\\myexamples\\sample.py"
```

---

But I'd actually prefer to write:

```
exec python [file nativename C:/tools/tcl/myexamples/sample.py]
```

Or, if it is in the same directory as the current Tcl script:

```
exec python [file nativename [file join [file dirname [info script]] sample.py]]
```

In general, some of that is stuff which you would record at the start of the script:

```
set ThisDir [file normalize [file dirname [info script]]]
```

and then you'd be able to do just this:

```
exec python [file nativename [file join $ThisDir sample.py]]
```

Comment: That avoids using `pwd` to get the current working directory. That might be the same as `$ThisDir`… or might not…

Answer (score 0):

for exec, only parameters with spaces in them need quotes, not the whole parameter list.

Using TKCon 2.7 (from an installation of ActiveState TCL 8.6) I tried the following:

```
exec "python c:\\writing\\scripts\\my_py.py"
```

Gave "python c:\writing\scripts\my_py.py" not found.

```
exec python c:\\writing\\scripts\\my_py.py
```

Ran the script properly. So did `exec "python" "c:\\writing\\scripts\\my_py.py".`

Creating a copy of my_py.py called `my_py space.py` and then runnung

```
exec python "c:\\writing\\scripts\\my_py space.py"
```

Also ran the script properly.

So it looks like exec needs quotes only for individual parameters with spaces in them.